# Problema com Mysql connector no rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Fala pessoal, eu não estou conseguindo cria um banco de dados para minha aplicação Rails ele informa o seguinte mensagem :

**Erro**

> C:\Ruby21-x64\DevKit\Projeto>rake db:create DL is deprecated, please
>   use Fiddle rake aborted! LoadError: Please install the mysql2 adapter:
>   `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~>
>   0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.3-x64-mingw32. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.)
>
> Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated
>   mysql2-0.4.3-x64-mingw32. Make sure all dependencies are added to
>   Gemfile.
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:create (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Eu não sei o motivo dele iniciar o msql2 na versão 0.3.10 e isso faz com que o banco de dados não seja criado. Alguma dica?

[**UPDATE**]

Quando eu falo para ele criar o projeto ele me mostra isso:

> You've installed the binary version of mysql2. It was built using
>   MySQL Connector/C version 6.1.6. It's recommended to use the exact
>   same version to avoid potential issues.
>
> At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files were
>   retrieved from:
>   http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32.zip
>
> This gem *includes* vendor/libmysql.dll with redistribution notice in
>   vendor/README.

Comment: Parece que o adaptador do mysql para o ruby não está instalado, use o comando `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` para instalar  o adapitador e use `gem update --system` para atualizar o mysql2, sua verção é `0.3.10` e o rails está requerindo a versão '0.4.3`

Comment: Eu já tente instalar o actierecord-mysql2-adapter porém ele fala que instalou mas quando dou o rake db:create novamente ele pede de novo

Comment: Quando eu falo para ele cria o projeto ele me mostra isso:

  You've installed the binary version of mysql2.
  It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.1.6.
  It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid potential issues.

  At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files were retrieved from:
  http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32.zip

  This gem *includes* vendor/libmysql.dll with redistribution notice in vendor/README.

Answer (score 0):

O problema não está no ruby, ele não está encontrando é os DLLs windows para conectar com mysql.

Baixe o arquivo que fala no erro:

```
http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32.zip
```

Depois extraia na pasta C:\mysql-connector

Depois rode no terminal:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector"'
```

E veja se instala.

Comment: Eu já fiz isso e mesmo assim ele continua com o mesmo erro, como eu disse após a instalação ele manda uma mensagem de erro do update que esta aqui.